# Confusing Array syntax php/html

Tags: php, html, arrays, syntax, brackets

Please help.
I've come across an input field like this and it is confusing me:

```
<input type="text" name="filter[][isranged][]">
```

I know it has to do with an array, but does this even make sense leaving the first and third bracket sets empty?
The brackets deal with creating keys for the values and what I was thinking is that this "filter" is an array that has another array in it (with a key called isranged) which has another array inside it. Am I correct? The brackets are confusing me.

The input is used to store a date like this: 09/03/2014

Comment: Dump code and you can see the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` is used to dynamically create the next element 0, 1, etc.  Given two inputs named like that you will get the following `$_POST` array:

```
Array
(
    [filter] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [isranged] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 'Value of first input'
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [isranged] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 'Value of second input'
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

`[filter]` gets a new numeric index for each input but the `[isranged]` array will always only contain 1 element `[0]` since they are part of different `filter[x]` arrays.

Comment: Thank you everyone this helped a bunch. So since it is an input the value inputted would be stored on the "inner" array at position [0] right? @AbraCadaver

Comment: For each input it would be stored at `$_POST['filter'][x]['isranged'][0]` where `x` is the index of `filter` and unique for each input. Edit to show input value.

Answer (score -1):

If you were to break that structure down into logical form it would be

```
filter = [
    { isranged: [ Many Values ] }
]
```

So basically filter is an array of an object that has a property of "isranged" that is an array itself.

Comment: Actually filter is an array with each element having an isranged array that has one element.